# System Verilog Enum Type Assignment

Tags: types, enums, system-verilog

I have a generic module in my library which is used multiple times at different places in the design.

```
    module generic #(
      parameter WIDTH = 1
    ) (
      input  logic [WIDTH-1:0] a,
      output logic [WIDTH-1:0] z
    );
    
    some function...
    
    endmodule
```

This is used in the design like so, where my_type_t is a `typedef enum logic` type defined elsewhere:

```
    my_type_t ope, res;
    generic #(
       .WIDTH ($bits(ope))
    ) ope_res (
      .a (ope),
      .z (res)
    );
```

When I compile, I get lint warnings in VCS:

```
    Warning-[ENUMASSIGN] Illegal assignment to enum variable
    ...
      Only expressions of the enum type can be assigned to an enum variable. 
      The type logic [WIDTH-1:0] is incompatible with the enum 'my_type_t'
      Expression: z
      Use the static cast operator to convert the expression to enum type.
```

Is there an easy way to fix this? The `generic` module is used for different `type`s, so that has to be a non-`type` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You better have good reason for casting in an out of an enum type. You can work around the error using the streaming unpack operator

```
generic #(
   .WIDTH ($bits(ope))
) ope_res (
  .a (ope),
  .z ({>>{res}})
);
```

The proper way to fix this is making `generic` using a parameterized type.

```
module generic #(
  parameter WIDTH = 1, type T = logic [WIDTH-1:0]
) (
  input  logic T a,
  output logic T z
);

// some function...

endmodule

module ...
 my_type_t ope, res;
 generic #(
   .T (my_type_t)
 ) ope_res (
  .a (ope),
  .z (res)
 );
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! I am aware of the parameterized type construct, however, we had some issues with some tools using it, so avoiding using it. JFYI, I changed `{>>res}` to `{>>{res}}` and it worked for me. I was thinking along those lines of using the streaming operator to unpack but wanted to know if there is a more elegant way. This works, so thanks again!

Comment: Casting to an enum type is always a questionable operation. There is no elegance there.